# Mysql - Problema de relación 3 tablas

Tags: mysql

recurro a los expertos ya que me encuentro bloqueado y sin más ideas por intentar.

### Antecedente

La base de datos ya se encuentra creada por una empresa de terceros por lo cual tenemos acceso a la base de datos, pero no podemos modificar la estructura, por lo cual cualquier cambio a nivel tabla no es posible. Métodos como utilizar variables o procedimientos son descartados ya que el acceso a la base es limitado a *queries* solo para reportes (Por mi fuera preferiría rehacer la base de datos, lamentablemente no es posible ni factible)

### Problemática

Existen 3 tablas: artículos, clientes, ventas, su estructura es:

```
CREATE TABLE clientes(
    id_cliente INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    clave VARCHAR(10),
    nombre VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_cliente)
);

CREATE TABLE articulos(
    id_articulo INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    clave VARCHAR(10),
    descripcion VARCHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_articulo)
);

CREATE TABLE ventas(
    id_ventas INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_articulo INT NOT NULL,
    id_cliente INT NOT NULL,
    cantidad   INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_ventas),
    INDEX (id_cliente),
    INDEX (id_articulo),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_cliente) REFERENCES clientes(id_cliente),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_articulo) REFERENCES articulos(id_articulo)
);
```

De éstas tablas (datos de ejemplo) tienen lo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO clientes (clave, nombre) 
VALUES 
('cli1', 'Luis'),
('cli2', 'Omar'),
('cli3', 'Isra')
;

INSERT INTO articulos (clave, descripcion)
VALUES
('art1', 'Clavos'),
('art2', 'Alambre'),
('art3', 'Varilla'),
('art4', 'Malla'),
('art5', 'Cemento');

INSERT INTO ventas (id_articulo, id_cliente, cantidad)
VALUES
(1,1,11),
(2,1,21),
(1,2,24),
(3,2,23),
(4,2,21),
(5,2,26),
(4,1,19),
(2,3,23);
```

Quedando sus datos (visualmente) así:

```
Clientes:

    id_cliente |    clave   |   nombre
    1               cli1        Luis
    2               cli2        Omar
    3               cli3        Isra
Articulos:
id_articulo |   clave   |   descripcion
1               art1        Clavos
2               art2        Alambre
3               art3        Varilla
4               art4        Malla
5               art5        Cemento
Ventas:
id_ventas   |   id_articulo |   id_cliente  |   cantidad 
1                   1               1               11
2                   2               1               21
3                   1               2               24
4                   3               2               23
5                   4               2               21
6                   5               2               26
7                   4               1               19
8                   2               3               23
```

El problema es al intentar mostrar el resultado (mediante *querie*) para poder visualizar todos los clientes con TODOS los artículos aunque no tenga ventas.
Se ha intentado con LEFT JOIN, CROSS JOIN UNION ALL y UNION y no se ha logrado el objetivo.

### Resultado esperado

Se espera poder ver todos los clientes, con todos los artículos aunque no tenga ventas (en éste caso mostrar NULL o 0) algo así:

```
id_cliente |    nombre  |   id_articulo |   descripcion |   cantidad
    1           Luis            1           Clavos              11               
    1           Luis            2           Alambre             21
    1           Luis            3           Varilla              0
    1           Luis            4           Malla               19
    1           Luis            5           Cemento              0
    2           Omar            1           Clavos              24
    2           Omar            2           Alambre              0
    2           Omar            3           Varilla             23
    2           Omar            4           Malla               21
    2           Omar            5           Cemento             26
    3           Isra            1           Clavos               0
    3           Isra            2           Alambre             23
    3           Isra            3           Varilla              0
    3           Isra            4           Malla                0
    3           Isra            5           Cemento              0
```

Espero puedan apoyarme y orientarme, y una disculpa anticipada si es que la información es incorrecta o como muestro la información no es la adecuada. 
De antemano gracias.

### Solución

Gracias a la ayuda, orientación y aporte de @patricio-moracho logre solucionar este problema.
La solución es mostrar todos los clientes que existen en la tabla de ventas y a su vez a cada uno de los clientes un listado con todos los artículos existentes (en éste caso 5), el código final ha quedado así:

```
SELECT
  c.id_cliente,
  c.nombre,
  a.id_articulo,
  a.descripcion,
  IFNULL (v.cantidad, 0)
FROM
  (SELECT
    c.id_cliente,
    c.nombre
  FROM
    clientes c
    LEFT JOIN ventas v
      ON v.id_cliente = c.id_cliente
  WHERE v.id_cliente IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY c.id_cliente) AS c
  LEFT JOIN articulos a
    ON 1 = 1
  LEFT JOIN ventas v
    ON v.id_articulo = a.id_articulo
    AND v.id_cliente = c.id_cliente;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Algo así:

```
SELECT c.id_cliente,
       c.nombre,
       a.id_articulo,
       a.descripcion,
       IFNULL(v.cantidad,0) cantidad
       FROM clientes c
       LEFT JOIN articulos a
           ON 1 = 1
       LEFT JOIN ventas v
           ON v.id_articulo = a.id_articulo
           AND v.id_cliente = c.id_cliente
       ORDER BY c.id_cliente,
                a.id_articulo;
```

Salida:

```
| id_cliente | nombre | id_articulo | descripcion | cantidad |
|------------|--------|-------------|-------------|----------|
|          1 |   Luis |           1 |      Clavos |       11 |
|          1 |   Luis |           2 |     Alambre |       21 |
|          1 |   Luis |           3 |     Varilla |        0 |
|          1 |   Luis |           4 |       Malla |       19 |
|          1 |   Luis |           5 |     Cemento |        0 |
|          2 |   Omar |           1 |      Clavos |       24 |
|          2 |   Omar |           2 |     Alambre |        0 |
|          2 |   Omar |           3 |     Varilla |       23 |
|          2 |   Omar |           4 |       Malla |       21 |
|          2 |   Omar |           5 |     Cemento |       26 |
|          3 |   Isra |           1 |      Clavos |        0 |
|          3 |   Isra |           2 |     Alambre |       23 |
|          3 |   Isra |           3 |     Varilla |        0 |
|          3 |   Isra |           4 |       Malla |        0 |
|          3 |   Isra |           5 |     Cemento |        0 |
```

El truco es hacer un `OUTER JOIN` con la tabla de `articulos` mediante:

```
LEFT JOIN articulos a
     ON 1 = 1
```

Si quieres listar solo los `clientes`que tuvieran al menos una venta:

```
SELECT c.id_cliente,
       c.nombre,
       a.id_articulo,
       a.descripcion,
       IFNULL(v.cantidad,0) cantidad
       FROM clientes c
       LEFT JOIN articulos a
           ON 1 = 1
       LEFT JOIN ventas v
           ON v.id_articulo = a.id_articulo
           AND v.id_cliente = c.id_cliente
       WHERE c.id_cliente IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_cliente FROM ventas)
       ORDER BY c.id_cliente,
                a.id_articulo;
```

Comment: exelente truco +1

Comment: Muchas gracias @patricio moracho, pero si quisiera obtener lo mismo, solo que únicamente con los clientes que aparecen en la tabla de ventas ¿Cómo podría alternar los LEFT JOIN para obtener el resultado? Ya que he alterado el orden de  las tablas, pero no obtengo la salida deseada. Esto por que en las tablas de producción la tabla clientes tiene mas de 16000 registros y la de ventas solo 30 clientes (la tabla es "nueva"), muchas gracias por tu apoyo.

Comment: @GianBros, revisa la última edición. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias @patricio-moracho, pero la intención es obtener todos los clientes de la tabla ventas y a su vez todos los artículos (aunque estos no hayan sido vendidos a ese cliente).

Comment: @GianBros, ahh, ok. Deberías agregar un `WHERE c.id_cliente IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_cliente FROM ventas)` a la consulta inicial.